# Ruby if conditional weirdly appears to run some code when the condition is false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a set-up where I have `Devise` being used as the main authentication handler for a Rails application and once in a while it appears to pull out an ActiveRecord Relation instead of a record, in the same way you might if you called `Type.where( name: "bob" )` for example.

In order to work around this ( I haven't spent much time with Devise and I don't have a lot of spare time to spend exploring it ) I just wanted to make sure my sign in checked and corrected this, so I wrote a section like this:

```
def authenticate_user_with_assignment!
    authenticate_user!
    logger.debug("User is #{current_user.inspect}")
    if ( current_user.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Relation) )
       logger.debug ("It is a relation!")
       current_user = current_user.first
    else
       logger.debug ("Not a relation.")
    end
    logger.debug("User is #{current_user.inspect}")
    # do some other stuff
end
```

I get output like this:

```
User is #<User id: 1, email: "admin@testaddress.com" ... etc >
Not a relation.
User is nil
```

If I comment out the `current_user = current_user.first` line, I get this:

```
User is #<User id: 1, email: "admin@testaddress.com" ... etc >
Not a relation.
User is #<User id: 1, email: "admin@testaddress.com" ... etc >
```

So somehow it appears to be ignoring the `logger` statements in my `if` condition there but running the assignment. I can't figure out why this is happening- any ideas?

Comment: How are you getting the value of current_user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
current_user = current_user.first
```

This creates a local variable, which shadows `current_user` method. Local variables are created as soon as parser notice them being declared, regardless whether assignment is actually executed or not, hence if the `if` condition is false, local variable `current_user` is declared and `nil`. You need to execute `current_user=` method instead:

```
self.current_user = current_user.first
```

If you have no such a method, define it.

Comment: Brilliant! That is indeed the solution. Thank you.